# Proving $(|a|+|c|)|x|+(|b|+|d|)|y|\le(|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|)\sqrt{\smash[b]{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: inequality

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, $v=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$. Show that $\|Av\|=M\|v\|$ for $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Solution:\begin{align*}
\|Av\| &= \sqrt{\smash[b]{(ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2}} \le |ax+by| + |cx +dy|\\
&\le |a||x|+|b||y|+ |c||x|+|d||y| = (|a|+|c|)|x| + (|b|+|d|)|y|.
\end{align*}
Here, I do not understand how this inequality holds:$$
(|a|+|c|)|x| + (|b|+|d|)|y| \le (|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|)\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$$
Could someone elaborate on this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{equation}
|x| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \qquad 
|y| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.
\end{equation}
Then the inequality you wrote follows immediately.